# Why do STUN requests fail when sent from certain websites?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

```
(async function()
{
    var iceServers = [{ urls: ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"] }];
    
    var peer = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers });
    peer.channel = peer.createDataChannel("channel");
    
    peer.onicecandidate = function(e)
    {
        if(e.candidate)
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e.candidate, null, '\t'));
        else
            console.log("DONE");
    };
    
    peer.onicecandidateerror = (e) => console.error(e);
    
    var offer = await peer.createOffer();
    await peer.setLocalDescription(offer);
})();
```

I use this sample code to test connecting to a STUN server and listing the generated ICE candidates. If I paste it into the console, depending on what website I'm currently visiting, the `icecandidateerror` event is triggered. The IPV6 address is full of x's and looks invalid. It happens in Chrome but not Firefox. This is the error I receive:

```
RTCPeerConnectionIceErrorEvent
address: "[0:0:0:x:x:x:x:x]"
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: RTCPeerConnection {…}
defaultPrevented: false
errorCode: 701
errorText: "STUN host lookup received error."
eventPhase: 0
hostCandidate: "[0:0:0:x:x:x:x:x]:33860"
isTrusted: true
path: []
port: 33860
returnValue: true
srcElement: RTCPeerConnection {…}
target: RTCPeerConnection {…}
timeStamp: 2621.4149999996152
type: "icecandidateerror"
url: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"
```

Here's a list of websites I've tried this code on:

- https://webrtc.github.io/samples/ - good
- https://webrtc.github.io/definitelya404page/ - good
- https://luisfonsivevo.github.io/samples/ - error (this is a fork of the above repo, using the same GitHub pages HTTP server)
- https://google.com/ - error
- https://codepen.io/ - good
- https://stackoverflow.com/ - error

What is it about certain domain names that would cause this error? Could it be a Chrome bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have acquired permissions for camera access for the origin of the sites that are marked 'good'. That changes the behaviour.

Mandatory disclaimer: webrtc was not build to gather ip addresses.

Comment: You were right; I had camera permissions enabled for the "good" websites. Our application only requires data channels so it slipped past me. Is there a way to resolve the error without requesting permission (other than not logging it)?

Comment: Ignore it. onicecandidateerror is diagnostic, it is only useful if things fail